# Do I need to upgrade my panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

So I went to look at my father in law’s panel, and as far as I can see, they look like they’re trying to draw too much amperage from the panel.

Does anything look amiss here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us with a close-up of the main on the far left, a picture of the labeling on the inside front door of this meter-main, and the square-footage of this house, to start?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel glad you are on the case.  The three single 20A breakers and the quadplex look interesting.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added the pictures. Square footage is 2,774.

Comment: Can you get us close-ups of the green label on one of the double-stuff breakers near the main breaker, and the white label on the breaker next to the far-right quadplex breaker? Furthermore, how many kitchen small appliance (receptacle) branch circuits does the  house have, is the range electric or gas, and what does the house have for a HVAC system?

Comment: I'm curious what makes you think you're trying to draw too much amperage? It's a 100A panel with a 100A main breaker - is that breaker tripping?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the breaker just left of the quadplex appears to be the same make (same design language) as the THQL2150 2-pole breakers in the middle.  In other words GE.

Comment: @Harper -- yeah, I'm suspecting the same, but want to make sure of it, and the label's not quite intelligible in the picture posted.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question nothing looks amiss as far as overloading is concerned. The way you know if a panel is over loaded is that the main circuit breaker trips out on overload. Prior to that if you are really concerned. Get an infrared thermometer and see if you can find any hot spots. Particularly around the connection and lug points. You want things to stay below 75C or 167F. Look for any discoloration or burn caused by overheating. Overheating is a sign of overloading due to the resistance of the bus and conductors.

Good luck

Comment: I think he may be OK on ampacity here (but won't be sure until I spin an Art. 220 for him); however, his panel's overstuffed on circuits and has some aliens in it to boot